# Custom JQuery validation with using $.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form something like this

> Form.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
<div class="form-input">First name = <input type ="text" name="fname" ><div class="error">First Div</div></div>
<div class="form-input">Last Name  = <input type="text" name ="lname" ><div class="error">Second Div</div></div>
<input type="submit" name ="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

I want to get Text() form each error class by jquery

> JQuery code :-

```
$(function() {
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');

    $inputs.each(function() {
        var data = $(this).val();
        alert($(this).html());

        /* Here i want to get each error class text  by jquery */ 

    });
});
```

Please give me some way to get something like this if this is possible by jquery

Thank you all :)

Comment: you have typos in your div class

Comment: To clarify what Edu said, you spelled "class" as "calss" twice

Comment: I think you need `$(this).next('.error').html()`

Comment: Thanks @akkatracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Thanks all for your help and time :)

i just successfully learn to create custom validation with jQuery using each function without using any plugin .

```js
$(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 $(".error").html("");
  var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');
    var values = {};
    
    $inputs.each(function() {
  var data = $(this).val();
  if(data == "")
     {
      var Error = '<font color="red"> ' + this.name +' is required </font><br>' ;
      $(this).next('.error').append(Error);
     }
     else
     {
      values[this.name] = data ;
     }
 });
  console.log(values);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
<div calss="form-input">First name = <input type ="text" name="firstname" ><div class="error"></div></div>
<div calss="form-input">Last Name  = <input type="text" name ="lastname" ><div class="error"></div></div>
<input type="submit" name ="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
<div id="error"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You should still mark an answer for your original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can just get the next sibling which is the error div by using next()

```
$(function() {
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $inputs = $('#myForm input[type="text"]');

    $inputs.each(function() {
        var data = $(this).val();
        alert($(this).html());

        /* Here i want to get each error class text  by jquery */ 
        alert($(this).next().text());

    });
});
```

Comment: just changed .html() to .text(), and so should show up. Also, i specified that the input is of type="text", otherwise you will get a third alert for the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do your `$inputs.each` like you do.

But format it like his, note the index and elem values.

```
$inputs.each(function(index, elem) {
    var $this = $(elem);
    var data = $this.val();
    alert($this.html());

    /* Here i want to get each error class text  by jquery */ 
    $this.siblings('.error').html()
});
```

Why you ask? well, if you are going to bind event handlers and using scopes in there, you're going to have big problems, because the this changes frequently then and becomes unpredictable.

By using the actual current element provided by the function you are 100% sure you're talking to the element you want.
By binding it to a variable `$this` in this case, you can pass exactly the current element on to other scoped functions.

Also look up on the jquery docs the documentations for the siblings function
https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

You can use class selector as:

```js
 $(function () {
        $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');
            $inputs.each(function () {
                var data = $(this).val();
                alert($(this).html());
            });
            $('.error').each(function () {
                alert($(this).html());
            });              
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
<div calss="form-input">First name = <input type ="text" name="fname" ><div class="error"></div></div>
<div calss="form-input">Last Name  = <input type="text" name ="lname" ><div class="error"></div></div>
<input type="submit" name ="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: please check you answer .. if possible then please answer with snippet .. thanks@kritika

Comment: This answer is to rough, it goes through all the .error fields instead of the error fields next to the input element like op requested.